# MySQL replication master-slave with 2 or more users in master

Tags: mysql, replication

I've just configured MySQL replication master-slave.
I have into master instance 3 user: root (with all privileges and grant), admin(with all privileges) and slaveUser(with replication salve privilege).
I've configured slave server to, and if I modify (with root user) in my master instance some resource this are replicated into slave.
Well, if I modify a resource, in master instance, with admin user this resource isn't modified into slave and I've this error

> Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user table' on query.
>   Default database: 'my_db'. Query: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO
>   'admin'@'%''

I've configured this on the same machine with 2 docker instances.

Any suggestions??

**EDIT**

This is my users on MASTER

```
+-----------+-----------+
| user      | host      |
+-----------+-----------+
| admin     | %         |
| root      | %         |
| userSlave | %         |
| mysql.sys | localhost |
+-----------+-----------+
```

and this is users on SLAVE

```
+-----------+-----------+
| user      | host      |
+-----------+-----------+
| root      | %         |
| mysql.sys | localhost |
+-----------+-----------+
```

Which kind of permission does admin need to write replication on slave??

**EDIT add SHOW SLAVE STATUS**

```
mysql> SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 172.17.0.3
                  Master_User: userSlave
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 317959980
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 5834
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1133
                   Last_Error: Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user table' on query. Default database: 'mydb'. Query: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%''
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 5621
              Relay_Log_Space: 317961680
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1133
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Can't find any matching row in the user table' on query. Default database: 'mydb'. Query: 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'%''
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 100
                  Master_UUID: 8527301e-9765-11e5-a957-0242ac110003
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: 
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind: 
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp: 151215 20:26:46
               Master_SSL_Crl: 
           Master_SSL_Crlpath: 
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set: 
            Executed_Gtid_Set: 
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB: 
                 Channel_Name: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR: 
No query specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Not `ON .`, rather `ON dbname.*` (good idea for applications) or `ON *.*` (might be appropriate for `admin`)

Comment: I've just updated my question. Do I need to create admin user on slave to?

Comment: `SHOW SLAVE STATUS;`  I want to make sure the Slave is connecting as userSlave, not admin.

Comment: OK, I've edited my question

Comment: I did not think you needed `GRANT USAGE TO 'admin'@'%';`, but try that on the Slave, then `START SLAVE;`

Comment: Slave is already up...If I modify some table in master with user root these are replicated into slave

Answer (score 0):

The error says in error you do not have `'admin'@'%'` on slaves. If you need these users on the slave, you should create `'admin'@'%'`. Or if you no need these users on slaves you may use:

1. `STOP SLAVE;`
2. `SET GLOBAL sql_slave_skip_counter = 1;`
3. `START SLAVE;`

Hope it helps you.